# How to add additional claims to be included in the access_token using ASP.Net Identity with IdentityServer4

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-identity

How to add additional claims to be included within the token?

As soon as the API receives the bearer token, the User.Identity object gets populated with the following claims.

```
[
  {
    "key": "nbf",
    "value": "1484614344"
  },
  {
    "key": "exp",
    "value": "1484615244"
  },
  {
    "key": "iss",
    "value": "http://localhost:85"
  },
  {
    "key": "aud",
    "value": "http://localhost:85/resources"
  },
  {
    "key": "aud",
    "value": "WebAPI"
  },
  {
    "key": "client_id",
    "value": "MyClient"
  },
  {
    "key": "sub",
    "value": "d74c815a-7ed3-4671-b4e4-faceb0854bf6"
  },
  {
    "key": "auth_time",
    "value": "1484611732"
  },
  {
    "key": "idp",
    "value": "local"
  },
  {
    "key": "role",
    "value": "AccountsManager"
  },
  {
    "key": "scope",
    "value": "openid"
  },
  {
    "key": "scope",
    "value": "profile"
  },
  {
    "key": "scope",
    "value": "roles"
  },
  {
    "key": "scope",
    "value": "WebAPI"
  },
  {
    "key": "scope",
    "value": "offline_access"
  },
  {
    "key": "amr",
    "value": "pwd"
  }
]
```

I want additional claims like `username, email, legacySystemUserId`, etc. These fields already exist in the `AspNetUsers` table (and doesn't repetitively exist in `AspNetUserClaims` table) and are available in ASP .Net Core application in my ApplicationUser object.

I want them to be included in access token that is returned after authenticating with username and password. Want to use the same in my WebAPI application that doesn't have access to the identity-server database and its own database has data stored based on user's email address not the UserId (which is a guid generated in ASP .NET Identity and received as SUB claim).

Answer (score 25):

I had been fighting this same issue for hours and finally pieced together the solution.  This [article](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/securing-net-core-web-api-identityserver4-using-owner-dalvandi-2) was a big help, but to summarize and share my implementation:

In order to get the claims assigned to the user and attach them to the access token, you need to implement two interfaces on the identity server: `IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator` and `IProfileService`. The following are my implementations of the two classes and are rough drafts, but they work.

**Be sure to get the latest version of IdentityServer4 - 1.0.2 at this time.

```c#
public class ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator : IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public Task ValidateAsync(ResourceOwnerPasswordValidationContext context)
    {
        var userTask = _userManager.FindByNameAsync(context.UserName);
        var user = userTask.Result;

        context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(user.Id, "password", null, "local", null);
        return Task.FromResult(context.Result);
    }
}
```

and

```c#
public class AspNetIdentityProfileService : IProfileService
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public AspNetIdentityProfileService(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
        var subject = context.Subject;
        if (subject == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context.Subject));

        var subjectId = subject.GetSubjectId();

        var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(subjectId);
        if (user == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid subject identifier");

        var claims = await GetClaimsFromUser(user);

        var siteIdClaim = claims.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress");
        context.IssuedClaims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Email, user.Email));
        context.IssuedClaims.Add(new Claim("siteid", siteIdClaim.Value));
        context.IssuedClaims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, "User"));

        var roleClaims = claims.Where(x => x.Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role");
        foreach (var roleClaim in roleClaims)
        {
            context.IssuedClaims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, roleClaim.Value));
        }
    }

    public async Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
    {
        var subject = context.Subject;
        if (subject == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context.Subject));

        var subjectId = subject.GetSubjectId();
        var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(subjectId);

        context.IsActive = false;

        if (user != null)
        {
            if (_userManager.SupportsUserSecurityStamp)
            {
                var security_stamp = subject.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "security_stamp").Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault();
                if (security_stamp != null)
                {
                    var db_security_stamp = await _userManager.GetSecurityStampAsync(user);
                    if (db_security_stamp != security_stamp)
                        return;
                }
            }

            context.IsActive =
                !user.LockoutEnabled ||
                !user.LockoutEnd.HasValue ||
                user.LockoutEnd <= DateTime.Now;
        }
    }

    private async Task<IEnumerable<Claim>> GetClaimsFromUser(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Subject, user.Id),
            new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.PreferredUserName, user.UserName)
        };

        if (_userManager.SupportsUserEmail)
        {
            claims.AddRange(new[]
            {
                new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Email, user.Email),
                new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.EmailVerified, user.EmailConfirmed ? "true" : "false", ClaimValueTypes.Boolean)
            });
        }

        if (_userManager.SupportsUserPhoneNumber && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.PhoneNumber))
        {
            claims.AddRange(new[]
            {
                new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.PhoneNumber, user.PhoneNumber),
                new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.PhoneNumberVerified, user.PhoneNumberConfirmed ? "true" : "false", ClaimValueTypes.Boolean)
            });
        }

        if (_userManager.SupportsUserClaim)
        {
            claims.AddRange(await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user));
        }

        if (_userManager.SupportsUserRole)
        {
            var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
            claims.AddRange(roles.Select(role => new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, role)));
        }

        return claims;
    }
}
```

Once you have those, they need to be added to your services in startup.cs:

```c#
services.AddTransient<IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator, ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator>();
services.AddTransient<IProfileService, AspNetIdentityProfileService>();
```

Here is a quick look at my config:

```c#
public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources()
{
    return new List<IdentityResource>
    {
        new IdentityResources.OpenId()
    };
}

public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources()
{
    return new List<ApiResource>
    {
        new ApiResource
        {
            Name = "api1",
            Description = "My Api",
            Scopes =
            {
                new Scope()
                {
                    Name = "api1",
                    DisplayName = "Full access to Api"
                }
            }
        }
    };
}

public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
{
    return new List<Client>
    {
        new Client
        {
            ClientId = "apiClient",
            ClientName = "Api Angular2 Client",
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,
            AlwaysSendClientClaims = true,
            AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true,
            ClientSecrets =
            {
                new Secret("secret".Sha256())
            },

            AllowedScopes =
            {
                "api1"
            }
        }
    };
}
```

After that, a call to the identity server from a client:

```c#
var discoTask = DiscoveryClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:5000");
var disco = discoTask.Result;

var tokenClient = new TokenClient(disco.TokenEndpoint, "apiClient", "secret");
var tokenResponseTask = tokenClient.RequestResourceOwnerPasswordAsync("user@domain.com", "my-password", "api1");

var tokenResponse = tokenResponseTask.Result;
var accessToken = tokenResponse.AccessToken;

if (tokenResponse.IsError)
{
    Console.WriteLine(tokenResponse.Error);
    return;
}
```

Inspect the token at jwt.io and see your results...

Comment: This is exactly the problem I'm having, only your solution doesn't seem to work insofar as the code in those two new classes never gets called. They're never even constructed. I'm not sure what I'm missing. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Phileosophos In the current version (4.1.1 as of today), you should add your IProfileService in Startup.cs like this, and you will find that it does get called by the framework: `.AddProfileService<AspNetIdentityProfileService>()`

You also do not need to include a custom implementation of IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator if you don't wish to.