# Should I send identity token to my api resources?

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect

I'm working with IdentityServer4 with the goal of protecting an resource api and exposing an identity server inside my organization.

So actually I have this elements:

- Authorization Server
- API Resources
- Client (SPA application)

I want to protect my API using scope and single actions accessed by user's roles. So for example I have this apis:

```
- API 1 (Scope API 1)
    - Action1.1 <-- Only admin
    - Action1.2 <-- Only manager
    - Action1.3 <-- Only manager

- API 2 (Scope API 2)
    - Action2.1 <-- Admin and manager
    - Action2.2 <-- Only users
    - Action2.3 <-- Only users
```

I know that OAuth2 protocol is for authorization (with its access_token) and OpenID Connect enriches OAuth2 protocol supporting authentication (with its identity_token).

I would know what is the best practices to achieve my goal. I've found two options:

1. Send to API Resource identity_token and authorization_token (so that I can view user's role by identity_token and is can access to the scope).
2. Adding role to access_token.

What is the best practice? Any advice is welcome

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion ,  you should not send the ID token to your resource . The ID Token is meant for the client application only. The client parses the token's contents and uses the user's information . The Access Token's purpose is to inform the API that the bearer of the token has been authorized to access the API and perform a predetermined set of actions according to scope claim in token .

Another point is per the OpenID Connect specification, the audience of the ID Token (indicated by the `aud` claim) must be the client ID of the application making the authentication request. If this is not the case, you should not trust the token. Conversely, an API expects a token with the `aud` value to equal the API's unique identifier. So in my opinion , include the permission claim in access token would be a better opinion .

Comment: Hi Nan Yu, do you know a way for include user's claims inside *access token* with identity server? Thank you

Comment: @ilMattion , you can click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44761058/how-to-add-custom-claims-to-access-token-in-identityserver4) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41687659/how-to-add-additional-claims-to-be-included-in-the-access-token-using-asp-net-id) for code samples.